# JavaScript-based applications and text browsers

Tags: browser, javascript, ssl, command-line, lynx

How to use complex AJAX applications with a lot of menus and with X.509 authentications in non-GUI mode with simple browsers?

For example, I can login to Webmoney from console using links/lynx/link2 (but not w3m), entering captcha (using aaxine) and do operations there, but can't login not using X.509 certificate (even if I try to separate SSL part using "socat tcp-l:... openssl:...:443,cert=extracted_from_firefox.pem")

Is there some program that behaves like fully-fledged browser (build DOM/execute JS/Support all features except of actually displaying things), but without GUI and dependencies on GUI libraries?

Comment: (considering proper SSL certificated as separate question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ELinks](http://elinks.or.cz/) can be compiled with both javascript and openssl. The javascript part comes from Mozilla's spidermonkey and has its limits. Depending on your setup it might also pull in lots of dependencies.

Comment: For my usecase just "openssl" is not enough. There should be something like generate/import/export of certificates and use them for authentication.

Compare to Firefox's Edit->Preferences->Advanced->Encryption->View certificates->Your certificates.

And it's JavaScript support seems very limited